# Problems with Wordpress Import

Tags: import, migration, export, xml

I have a VPS hosting account with Web Fusion and am migrating one of my Wordpress sites to it.

The Wordpress export file is about 29 MB. At first i encountered an Internal Server Error after attempting the first upload. After doing some research and checking the server logs it appeared to be a problem with the FCGID and PHP ini settings.

The Host is using a Plesk control panel through which I increased all the memory limits and restrictions to 64M and allowed file uploads.

I have also gone through changing the FCGID limits in the Apache modules and another 2 config files on the VPS.

It all seemed to go OK. I restarted the server to apply the changes, however now when I attempt to upload the XML file via the Wordpress Admin Panel I get is the Import Wordpress title and a blank page. No posts are uploaded and it does not give me any further options about the media import. There also no further loggs in the error_log file on the server to suggest any issues

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try paring down your XML import file to just two or three posts (see [this answer for more details](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113067/32110)) and see if it imports those successfully.